# IOS 6 Safari not exhibiting bug when debugging with Web Inspector, how to find bug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, ios6, safari

I'm trying to debug a bug that's only showing on IOS 6 Safari, from what I know.  Chrome and Opera don't exhibit this bug.

I have reproduced the bug on my iPad 2 and the iOS Simulator, but only in the production environment.  However, when I go into the safari Web Inspector (either iPad or simulator), the bug no longer occurs.

Any idea how to figure out what type of error I'm dealing with?  I believe it's a JS error, but don't know where.

-- UPDATE --

To give a better idea of the workflow:

I load the page the exhibits the error.  I plug in the iPad to my Mac, open a Safari window, then open a Develop > iPad > myTab.  Then I hit reload on the page, and it doesn't exhibit the error.

-- UPDATEx2 --

I was able to get an error by opening it up in Opera Mini, then opening a tab and going to "server:console", which showed the error.  Not exactly helpful when dealing with Safari-exclusive bugs, give it seemed to work.

And btw, the bug was an undefined JS variable.

Comment: do you get any messages on safari web console? also make sure the right tab it is selected

Comment: 1) Share code
2) have you checked for console.log() calls? I can't remember which browser it is, but it might be that the console object doesn't exist until you have the debugger open, and your code is choking on that and throwing an error.

Comment: also try refreshing the simulator from safari web console, CMD+R and make sure the right log it is selected, safari tends to show older logs as default

Comment: I'm confused on how to get messages on the safari web console, perhaps.  I have the iOS Simulator, and the Safari Web Inspector open, where you can enter console statements.  However, there are no errors or messages.

Comment: try with the basic.. console.log("Hello world"); if you see that it is working

Comment: I'm only able to reproduce it currently in prod, not in a dev or build environment.  Currently working on that part.

Comment: The odd part I'm trying to understand is why the debugger alters the execution and how to work around it.

Comment: Is your prod app an app that is coming from the App Store? You can't use the Safari debugger on a PhoneGap/Cordova app that is installed from the App Store... but if this is just a website that you're pointing at, you should be able to get the app to register when hooked to the Mac and the page is loaded in Safari.

Comment: This is a website.  My current thought is that an event is just being missed somehow, perhaps the listener isn't setup at the time it fires, so there's no actual error to catch

Comment: Just stumbled upon this: I have the exact same problem. It definitely seems that connecting an iOS device to the Mac alters the mobile Safari behaviour. Did you ever find what happened (I tried the Opera mini trick but it did not work for me)?

Comment: I never pushed through, as I found a workaround.  If you find an answer, be sure to post it, though!

Comment: Thanks for posting an update. I'm currently facing the same issue on Safari (for a desktop).