# Safari 6 not exhibiting bug when debugging with Web Inspector, how to find bug?

Tags: javascript, safari, web-inspector

I am running into a javascript error when I visit my site on Safari, which prevents the rest of the site being rendered. When I have the inspector open when visiting the site, the error does not happen. I tried to reproduce the error on Chrome, Firefox, IE, and iOS Safari, and everything worked fine. I also tried to reproduce the error in my development environment on Safari, but no luck, the site fully loaded.

The error is "TypeError: Type error"

I have found a couple of questions on stackoverflow that were experiencing very similar issues but they had no solutions that worked for me.
[Javascript type error in Safari 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598332/javascript-type-error-in-safari-6)
[IOS 6 Safari not exhibiting bug when debugging with Web Inspector, how to find bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457034/ios-6-safari-not-exhibiting-bug-when-debugging-with-web-inspector-how-to-find-b)

I am not sure where to go from here.

-- Update -- ISSUE FOUND AND FIXED

The issue was a `string.toString()` call in handlebars.runtime.js
Had to change it to `"" + string;`

You can read more about it here https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/535

Comment: Im using 'try catch' in javascript. try{ //codes }catch(e){alert(e); // it will alert if it finds bugs}

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in Handlebars 1.1.0 release.

Comment: Yes it is, I should have mentioned that in my update. I am using handlebars_assets gem which is still using 1.0.0. So I had to include the handlebars.runtime.js with the updated code, in my vendor/assets/javascripts folder to override the one from the gem.